# issue with aiohttp POST for a binary file upload

Tags: python-3.x, http-post, python-requests, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have successfully used the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module to upload a binary file (jpg), with something like the following:

```
upload_url = 'http:10.1.1.1:8080/api/media/photo'
headers = {'Authorization': token_string, 'Content-Type': 'image/jpg'}
data = open('photo.JPG', 'rb')
params = {'name': 'photo.JPG'}
r = requests.post(upload_url, params=params, data=data, headers=headers)
```

Now trying to do this with [aiohttp](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.org/en/latest/client.html) client.  This is what I have so far:

```
def upload_photos(token):
    upload_url = '10.0.1.1:8080/api/media/photo'
    headers = {'Authorization': token, 'Content-Type': 'image/jpg'}
    data = {'file': open('photo.JPG', 'rb')}
    params = {'name': 'photo.JPG'}
    r = yield from aiohttp.request('post', upload_url, params=params, data=data, headers=headers)

if __name__ == '__main__':     
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(upload_photos(token))
```

But I am getting a 400 back, with `{"detail": "Specified value is invalid: Invalid Content-Length specified"}`.
It's as if it's not properly sending the photo.jpg.  The aiohttp docs mentione multi-part encoded files and streaming, but that's not whant I want here.

**How do I form a similar POST w/ binary file like in requests, but with aiohttp?**

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for a bug report. As workaround I guess to use chunked transfer encoding:

```
headers['Transfer-Encoding'] = 'chunked'
r = yield from aiohttp.request('post', upload_url, params=params, data=data, headers=headers, chunked=1024)
```

The recipe should work, at least we have very simular code in our test suite: https://github.com/KeepSafe/aiohttp/blob/master/tests/test_client_functional.py#L322

I'll try to fix *Content-Length* calculation for your uploading way in next aiohttp release.

Comment: Wow, thanks @Andrew.  The last thing I would have thought was that what I saw was a aiohttp bug....I always blame myself first for not knowing what I am doing ;-).

Comment: Still not able to do it...here is my code snippet...am I doing something else wrong? `headers = {'Authorization': token_string, 'Content-Type': 'image/jpg', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'}
    
    params = {'name': 'photo.JPG'}

    with open('photo.JPG', 'rb') as f:
        r2 = yield from aiohttp.request('post', upload_url, params=params, data=f, chunked=1024, headers=headers)`

Comment: I guess to send file content, not file object. Something like `data=f.read()`.